# Finding a weight function for Bessell Sturm-Liouville problem with some boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions, sturm-liouville

I have a Bessel differential equation 
$$r^2R'' + rR' + k^2r^2R=0$$

on $r = (R_1, R_2)$ with boundary conditions

$$R'(r=R_1) = A$$
$$R'(r=R_2) = 0$$

where $A$ is some constant I can determine through a physical background of the problem. The solution is $$R(r) = J_0(kr) + B Y_0(kr)$$where $B=-\frac{J_1(kR_2)}{Y_1(kR2)}$.

How would you go about finding a weight function, that would give orthogonality to the solutions of the problem?

Also is there a way to find a weight function for any given boundary conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weight function $w$ is the coefficient of $\lambda u$ when the differential equation is put in Sturm–Liouville form,
$$ -(pu')' + qu = \lambda w u. \tag{1} $$
It is the same for *any* Sturm–Liouville problem that uses this equation (i.e. with appropriate boundary conditions; the actual location of the boundary is irrelevant).

---

For this equation, the Sturm–Liouville form is
$$ -(rR')' = k^2rR, $$
so $p(r)=r$, $q(r)=0$, $\lambda=k^2$, and $w(r)=r$.

---

This isn't quite enough, however: as my colleague in the comments notes, the boundary conditions here are not Sturm–Liouville boundary conditions. Your asserted solution is missing a vital component: an overall constant. We can then see that the problem has a continuous variety of solutions: if we let $R_k(r)$ be your solution, then $AR_k(r)/R'_k(R_1)$ satisfies both boundary conditions for any $k$ provided that $R'_k(R_1) \neq 0$. It is not possible to impose orthogonality conditions on these functions: there are simply too many of them.

---

If we impose the condition $R_k(R_1)=0$, the problem becomes a proper Sturm–Liouville problem, and we can impose the extra boundary condition at $R_1$ to obtain the correct scaling for the functions (given above). We can then check orthogonality using the following:

If we take $u,v$ *any* solutions to (1) with respective eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$, we also have the formula
$$ \int w(x)u(x)v(x) \, dx = \frac{-p(x)}{\lambda-\mu}(u'(x)v(x)-v'(x)u(x)) $$
(differentiate the right-hand side and use (1) to see why).

It is clear that this is zero when $r=R_2$, and if $r=R_1$, the new boundary condition $R_k(R_1)=0$ makes the other boundary term zero.

Comment: Sturm-Liouville problems require homogenous endpoint conditions.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts You're right, thank you for pointing that out. I've updated my answer.

Comment: So my problem has to do with heat diffusion, it is a hollow cylinder which is insulated on the outside wall (at $R_2$) and with heat flux flowing into the inside, which gives a condition $\frac{d}{dr}T(r=R_1^+,t)=\frac{d}{dt}T(r=R_1^-,t)$, where T(r<R_1) has no radial dependence. If eigenfunctions are not orthogonal, how would I go about solving that for a given initial condition?

Comment: @PavesicL In such cases, it is normal to build the solution out of several functions: first, find a function $g$ so that $u=T-g$ satisfies homogeneous boundary conditions. Then if $T$ satisfies $LT = 0$ where $L$ is the differential operator, then $u$ satisfies $Lu = -Lg$, and we then expand the right-hand side in eigenfunctions of $L$ and integrate. See e.g. http://www.eng.famu.fsu.edu/~dommelen/pdes/style_a/svbex.html for the procedure.

Comment: I still can't solve my problem :( Another question, this additional function $g$ has to solve the heat equation AND satisfy boundary conditions am i correct?

Comment: No, $g$'s purpose is to make the boundary conditions homogeneous so that Sturm–Liouville theory can be used. It can be anything that satisfies the boundary conditions and is differentiable enough that you can apply $L$ to it.

Comment: I tried finding a function like that would satisfy my conditions($\frac{dT(R_2, t)}{dr} = 0$ and $\frac{dT(R_1,t)}{dt} = C \frac{dT(R_1,t)}{dr}$) but can't think of anything. I tried polynomials and stuff like that, as from the physical aspect I probably expect a constant to be enough, but it didn't work. Could you maybe help me? Is there a smart way to do it or do i just have to guess?